# issue in publishing story on facebook via non developer facebook accounts

Tags: android, facebook

i am trying to publish a story on facebook using facebook android api. the problem i am observing is that stories from only those accounts are published on fb who are registered as developers of that application on developers.facebook.com

Can you please suggest what could be the reason of such behavior, am i missing something that should be included to post on facebook using other facebook accounts as well?

following is the code that i am using to post on the fb:
Android app:

```
private void publishStory() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null){

        // Check for publish permissions    
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("couponId " + deal.couponId);
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
   //           params.putString("deal", "http://69.28.95.165/atc/cdv2/web/FBredirect.php?index="+deal.couponId);
   //           params.putString("deal", "http://69.28.95.165/atc/cdpk/web/FBredirect.php?index="+deal.couponId);
        System.out.println("Publishing on fb::::");
        params.putString("deal", "http://texastech.tk/cd3/FBredirect.php?index="+deal.couponId);
        Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {


            }
        };

        Request request = new Request(session, "me/citydealweb:avail", params, 
                              HttpMethod.POST, callback);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();

    }

}
```

following is my server side script:

```
<?php
 $index = $_REQUEST['index'];
include 'DBConfig.php';
$query = "select * from outlets o join coupons c on o.OutletId=c.OutletId where c.CouponId=$index";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 $image = "img/citydeals.jpg";
if($row['OutletImage'] != ""){
   $image = $row['OutletImage'];
 }
 ?>
 <html>
     <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# citydealweb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/citydealweb#">
    <title>Geeky N Techy</title>

    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1420361048183154" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $row['OutletName']?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://texastech.tk/cd3/<?php echo $image;?>" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://texastech.tk/cd3/FBredirect.php?index=<?php echo $index;?>" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="citydealweb:deal" />

    <script>
    window.location.replace("http://texastech.tk/cd3/index.php?index=<?php echo $index;?>");
    </script>
 </html>
```

Comment: If you go to your app's settings, and click on the "Status & Review" tab in the left menu, there's an option for "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" Turn that on to be YES if you want anyone to be able to use your app's Facebook features.

Comment: it is already on YES

Comment: there is one other option for submitting the app before using for general public, does that has to do something with this issue?

Comment: Yes, your app's custom actions (as well as additional permissions) need to be approved before they can be use by public users.

Comment: i got the publish story permission approved but still not able to publish stories via non-developer facebook accouts

Comment: @WasifTanveer, What's the error you're getting back? Are you able to reproduce this using Graph Explorer? If your App is not in development mode, every user should be able to publish a story. I'd suggest to check your access tokens, permissions granted but most important, the error.

Comment: how to know the app is in development mode? i cannot see any error, it just does not publish